# Notepad++ create contents (functions) using a template and a list

Tags: notepad++, macros

I want to create similar functions with its name obtained from a list from a file.
Also its content will also use the name from the list.

example: 
list is written in file (fun_list.txt) as:

```
CLK_A_0
CLK_A_1
CLK_B_0
CLK_B_1
CLK_B_2
..
..
```

and my function template is defined in (fun_template.txt)

```
uint32 enable_###(boolean val)
{
   ### =  val;
}
```

expected result in one single output file as (fun_clock.c):

```
uint32 enable_CLK_A_0(boolean val)
{
   CLK_A_0 =  val;
}
uint32 enable_CLK_A_1(boolean val)
{
   CLK_A_1 =  val;
}
uint32 enable_CLK_B_0(boolean val)
{
   CLK_B_0 =  val;
}
uint32 enable_CLK_B_1(boolean val)
{
   CLK_B_1 =  val;
}
uint32 enable_CLK_B_2(boolean val)
{
   CLK_B_2 =  val;
}
..
```

How do I achieve this in notepad++.
I assume using macros we should be able to do this.

I don't have any restrictions for file names (or to be in separate files), I want to create these functions easily rather than copying it manually.

If not in notepad++, if there is some easy solution in windows (cmd) or linux that too would be good.

Answer (score 3):

This small perl script does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# define and open the three files
my $file_lst = 'fun_list.txt';         # give the full path if doesn't run in the same dir
my $file_tpl = 'fun_template.txt';
my $file_out = 'fun_clock.c';

open my $fh_l, '<', $file_lst or die "Unable to open '$file_lst': $!";
open my $fh_t, '<', $file_tpl or die "Unable to open '$file_tpl': $!";
open my $fh_o, '>', $file_out or die "Unable to open '$file_out': $!";

# read template file in "slurp" mode
my $tpl;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $tpl =  <$fh_t>;
}
# read the list file and replace all ### in the template with the line in  list file
while(<$fh_l>) {
    chomp;
    (my $tmp = $tpl) =~ s/###/$_/g;
    print $fh_o $tmp;
}
```